# Bootstrap 4 Navbar on Two Lines

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow so I do apologize in advance if this question has already been asked (although I did look for some time and did not see anything related).
I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 Alpha and trying to get a navbar to show, however it is showing on two lines and not in one single line.  I used the navbar code straight from bootstrap 4's website, however it still shows as follows with two lines

[Two line navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezkN.png)

I'm not sure at this point if I have not included something in the file because I have jQuery, Tether, Bootstrap JS, and bootstrap.min.css as well as one scss file with no styling.  Can someone please help me understand why the navbar is still not showing in a  straight line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this below code. It is working perfectly fine and you will get the output what you want.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js""></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

**Output**

[image: Here is the output.]

Comment: thanks I thought i used this but something went weird..all good now thank you

Comment: If it worked for u, pic this answer as selected @vski if still need some assist tell me